# can you have multiple columns have a rowspan in the same table

Tags: html, html-table

i want a table with three column and i want the first and third column to both have rowspan="3" but the second column i want data on "each" row. is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```html
<table>
<tr><td rowspan="3">1</td><td>2</td><td rowspan="3">3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Crazy, I literally typed out this post word for word and was just about to post it heh.